# How to delete same pointer in different std::vector's?

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector, game-loop

My game's main loop looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;

for(size_t i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
{
     states[i]->Update();
     states[i]->Draw();

}
```

Their is a flaw with this though. I can't modify the vector (delete a state) during the iteration because if I deleted the current state the iteration is on then it breaks obviously because there is no state to call update and draw on. So I thought it would be a good idea to make a vector of states that should be added to the `states` vector and make a vector of states that should be deleted to the `states` vector. Then after the loop is over modify the `states` vector and no problems will occur mid iteration.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> states;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> statesToBeAdded;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<State>> statesToBeRemoved;

for(size_t i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
{
    states[i]->Update();
    states[i]->Draw();

}

for(size_t i = 0; i < statesToBeAdded.size(); i++)
{
    states.push_back(std::move(statesToBeAdded[i]));
}
statesToBeAdded.clear();

for(size_t i = 0; i < statesToBeRemoved.size(); i++)
{
    states.erase(std::remove(states.begin(), states.end(), statesToBeRemoved[i]), states.end());
}
statesToBeRemoved.clear(); //error is thrown here
```

I can't delete states from the `states` vector though, an error is thrown on the `statesToBeRemoved.clear()` line and I think it's because when I call the `states.erase(...)` line it deletes the element from the `states` vector which consequently nullifies the same element in the `statesToBeRemoved` vector since that element points to an object that no longer exists.

You can't just delete a std::unique_ptr without destroying what the pointer points to so I don't think there is a way to delete the element from the `states` vector without nullifying the element in the `statesToBeRemoved` vector. So how do solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Uh... it's called a **unique** pointer for a reason. You shouldn't have two of those pointing to the same thing, **ever**. Decide what your ownership semantics should be and change your pointer types accordingly.

Comment: It looks like `statesToBeAdded` and `statesToBeRemoved` should contain just `State*` and `states` should have the `unique_ptr` instances (and therefore ownership).

Comment: do show the definition of `State`. and best, show a complete, small program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different pointer types cater for different ownership semantics:

- `unique_ptr`s are for unique ownership, this is why your current code does not work
- `shared_ptr`s are for shared ownership - when the last `shared_ptr` managing an object goes out of scope, it is destroyed
- raw pointers (`*`) don't really say anything about the semantics they are modeling, but you have to enforce all constraints manually - that's what makes them dangerous. They are however, safe, (and in my opinion the sensible choice) for pointers that do never have ownership of the object pointed to.

So: Your `statesToBeAdded` is safe as long as you can guarantee that you never have anything in there that isn't already in `states`. `statesToBeRemoved` is different: The objects are already there and in `states`, and it would make sense to have `states` take ownership of the objects  - hence raw pointers would be a fair choice for `statesToBeRemoved`.

Note that all this is based on the few lines of code you have shown, depending on the circumstances it may well be that it makes sense to store `State`s instead of `unique_ptr<State>`s in your `states`, etc ...